# How to make binding between comboBox item tag

Tags: wpf, xaml, dictionary, combobox, itemtemplate

I define `Dictionary` that contain int as key and string as value `Dictionary<int, string >`. I made binding between `ComboBoxItem` and this `Dictionary`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding myDictionary}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Tag="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, i want to make a Binding between the item selected tag. How can i do it ? 
I know how to do it in case i want to have the SelectedValue of the combo (get the text selected in the combo)  ==> but i need the tag and not the text ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to SelectedItem.Tag

Example:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbDictionary,Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"/>
```